# How to fix Youtube API results title that are returned encoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-data-api

I'm using [youtube-search 1.1.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search) to find videos. The problem is that i get the results titles encoded with `&amp;` or `&#39;` instead of just `&` and `'` and more.

example of one result i got from the example code below (again, added spaces between characters intentionally):
`title: "Post Malone - &quot;Wow.&quot; (Official Music Video)"`

Tried solving this by decodeURI ,decodeURIComponent or unescape which didn't help.
Used a direct call for [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) and got the same results.
What am i missing?

```
var youtubeSearch = require("youtube-search")

var opts = {
  maxResults  : 15,
  key         : 'MY_API_KEY',
  part        : 'snippet',
  type        : 'video',
};

youtubeSearch('post malone', opts, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);

  console.dir(results);
});
```

Comment: If you don't mind using libraries a quick search found me [He.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)

Comment: I've seen this behavior myself for more than two weeks now. My understanding is that this issue is in fact a *bug* of the API. Maybe you should file a bug report to https://issuetracker.google.com.

Comment: Searched the google issue tracker and found this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/128673539

Comment: @ramidulman That is not the same issue. JSON strings must escape the double quote character using a backslash if the string itself contains this character. eg `"""` is not valid while `"\""` is valid. The linked issue has nothing to do with HTML encoding.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: sorry, but you are wrong: rami dulman did linked correctly his issue to Google's issue #128673539. See my comment https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673539#comment8.

Comment: @stvar The issue might link to this question, but that doesn't make it right. Not escaping JSON string characters that should be escaped conform the [json.org](http://json.org/) specification. Is something completely different than retuning escaped HTML characters in the string. Keep in mind that I'm not denying that this might be a bug. It is however not the same bug.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: Well, to be more accurate, the initiator of Google's issue #128673539 is itself wrong from the start. He/She copy-pasted an API response text *displayed* on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets. Obviously, that text is not valid JSON. Yet the API returns valid JSON (just do a wget/curl on https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$YOUR_APP_KEY&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=11&q=DING%20DING). Therefore, the initiator is wrong because his/her issue in not an API issue, but an issue of the text *displayed* on the docs web page...

Comment: @3limin4t0r: ... However, the issue of embedded HTML char entities is new and real. I experienced it as such and, as far as I can see, it's due to Google's API changing behavior without documenting it.

Comment: @stvar If the behaviour is indeed undocumented and differs from expectations a new issue should be created. Assuming that there isn't one already. If it turns out to be a duplicate the Google staff will merge the issue together or close one leaving a reference to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the DOM Parser

```
var parser = new DOMParser;

let finalResult = parser.parseFromString(results, "text/html")
console.log(finalResult.body.innerHtml); // will turn &amp; to &
```

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering whether this is the correct solution, do I need to use a whole DOMParser just for decoding Youtube video titles in my React component?

Comment: Seems like @ErikAGriffin mentioned an alternative library which is much smaller - unescape. https://github.com/jonschlinkert/unescape/

EDIT: found a more recent package by the known sindresorhus, was updated 3 months ago vs unescape's 2 years ago.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-goat

Answer (score 0):

After finding a related ticket on google's issue tracker:
[issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/128673539](http://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/128673539) and got a response from google that this is the expected behaviour and they won't fix it, i just used user [3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r) suggestion and decoded the return value title using [he.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library, it's the idle way to solve this but i had no intention to wait for google to come around from their decision...

so, my solution goes like that:

```
var youtubeSearch = require("youtube-search")
let he            = require('he');

var opts = {
  maxResults  : 15,
  key         : 'MY_API_KEY',
  part        : 'snippet',
  type        : 'video',
};

youtubeSearch('post malone', opts, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  results = results.map(item => {
        item.snippet.title = he.decode(item.snippet.title);
        return item;
   });
  console.dir(results);
});
```

Comment: This library is significantly smaller if all you need is to unescape html entities: [unescape](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/unescape/)