# Youtube Api search results have Quotation Marks error

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I try to use YouTube API, but it has Quotation Marks problem.

```
        SearchResource.ListRequest searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
        searchListRequest.ChannelId = channelId;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        searchListRequest.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date;
        SearchListResponse searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();
```

I expect the output of" Mr Beasts plants 20'000'000 TREES" but the actual output is "Mr Beasts plants 20'000'000 TREES".
I expect the output of "Rating James Charles "Tati" Apology video" but the actual output is "Rating James Charles "Tati" Apology"

Comment: Looking at the text of your issue I see no problem: both expected and actual outputs are identical! Only looking at the source text of your issue I see what you mean. Isn't it Ironical that, while you complain about API's quoting issues, yourself exhibit by your text issues of the same nature?

Comment: This is related to [How to fix Youtube API results title that are returned encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55385560).

Comment: I guess stackoverflow has changed. actual output is &quot;

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of the API (which I already quoted above).

Since your context is C# and .NET, you should employ either of the standard methods [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode) or [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode) to replace all HTML character references (entities) obtained from the API.